# Use keywords-field for sorting biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I want to create a bibliography that groups references together. I thought I could add keywords and then use `\printbibliography[keyword=a]` for example. To use `style=numeric`, I would like to sort by the keywords as well.

I know, I could add `keywords` for grouping and additionally add `presort` so that the sorting works accordingly. But I thought it would be nice to have it in one single key, so I wrote a sorting scheme which results in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=sample
]{biblatex}
\DeclareSortingScheme{sample}{
    \sort{
        \field{keywords}
    }
}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{b}, filler text \autocite{a}.

\printbibliography[keyword=a]
\printbibliography[keyword=b]
\end{document}
```

The mybib.bib looks like this:

```
@misc{a,
    keywords = {a},
    title = {{Keyword A}},
    author = {Myself},
    year = {2000}
}

@misc{b,
    keywords = {b},
    title = {{Keyword B}},
    author = {Myself},
    year = {2000}
}
```

Unfortunately, 'b' is assigned [1] while 'a' is assigned [2]. Now I guess this is somehow due to the fact that `keywords` is a "Separated value field" and there is no sorting defined for those kinds of fields? But I could not find anything about that, so my question is: Why doesn't it work and where is it written in the biblatex documentation that keywords can not be used for sorting?

Comment: `biber` can't sort on keywords at the moment because no-one has ever requested it. `keywords` is a CSV field and so the semantics of sorting on this field is not so clear - I could add this functionality but it's not obvious it's that useful since keywords are normally used to filter bibliography list after `biber` has run, in `biblatex`. If you can think of a use-case that really does need this, please open a ticket on the biber github tracker.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an X-Y-problem. Maybe you are just looking for the `defernumbers` option?

Comment: @PLK Thanks, that's the information I was looking for. And no, it is not really necessary to have this functionality, maybe it is better like this because it does make sense. But I would have liked a note in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use `\DeclareSourcemap` to copy the value of the `keywords` list in a different field (let us say `usera`) and use this field to sort the entries.

Here is the  definition of the source map

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval, final]
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{sample}{
    \sort{
        \field{usera}
    }
}
```

With these modifications the MWE produces:

[image]